# How can I run Java on a grsec-hardend Arch Linux kernel with paxd?

Tags: security, configuration, java, grsecurity

I have Arch Linux with the latest grsec-hardened 4.9.x Linux kernel with paxd installed. But because of this when I try to run Java I get the following error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000035ea1000000, 2555904, 1) failed; error='Operation not permitted' (errno=1)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 2555904 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/[username]/hs_err_pid2813.log
```

Now, I got this error in the past and I managed to tell it to allow Java to do this, however I cannot remember nor find the resources of how to do it. I have looked at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27300434), but alas, my system tells me that is cannot find the command `paxctl` even though I have all the grsec related utilities installed mentioned on the Arch wiki.

So how do I make it allow Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paxctl` should work for you,

```
root #paxctl -h
PaX control v0.7
Copyright 2004,2005,2006,2007,2009,2010,2011,2012 PaX Team <pageexec@freemail.hu>

usage: paxctl <options> <files>

options:
    -p: disable PAGEEXEC        -P: enable PAGEEXEC
    -e: disable EMUTRAMP        -E: enable EMUTRAMP
    -m: disable MPROTECT        -M: enable MPROTECT
    -r: disable RANDMMAP        -R: enable RANDMMAP
    -x: disable RANDEXEC        -X: enable RANDEXEC
    -s: disable SEGMEXEC        -S: enable SEGMEXEC

    -v: view flags          -z: restore default flags
    -q: suppress error messages -Q: report flags in short format
    -c: convert PT_GNU_STACK into PT_PAX_FLAGS (see manpage!)
    -C: create PT_PAX_FLAGS (see manpage!)
```

Usually I would disable all restrictions like this,

```
paxctl -pemrxs `which java`
```

Though you can also set the flags more directly without needing `paxctl`. So for instance if you wanted to disable the `mr` ones you would do:

```
sudo setfattr -n user.pax.flags -v "mr" `which java`
```

Comment: It tells me that the command `paxctl` cannot be found. What package is it in? I'm sure I have all the ones mentioned on the wiki, but perhaps not.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Try AUR https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/paxctl/

Comment: @ParanoidPanda In addition to `pemrxs` arguments, you might also need to add `-c` or `-C` to the command line

Comment: Ah... I see! That is the problem, I don't have anything from the AUR installed. I would also rather not install anything from there for security reasons. But as I have previously done it through a command which wasn't `paxctl`, I am sure that there is another way. I remember giving something the `-m` flag and the file path and it working. Do you not know of a different way of doing this other than through `paxctl` because I would like to avoid packages in the AUR?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda it's a small program, you can build it from source https://pax.grsecurity.net/paxctl-0.9.tar.gz

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at that. Thanks! I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: It should also be mentioned though that all `paxctl` really does is set flags, so if you want to do the `-mr` one then all you need to do is: `sudo setfattr -n user.pax.flags -v "mr" /path/to/file`.